# How to retrieve complete data from two tables based on user_name along with max date in Hive

Tags: mysql, hive

For example I have a table A and B with the following data:

**A:**

```
user_name date1 count1 count2
X          15     1      1
X          30     1      3
Y          04     1      3
```

**B:**

```
user_name date1 count3 count4 status
X          15     11     1      Y
X          30     13     3      N
Y          04     16     3      NA
```

How to join these 2 tables for each feedname with max date.
I need the output like these:

```
username date1 count1 count4 status
X         30    1      3        N
```

like these way.
Can anyone plz help in these situation.

Comment: Does every (user_name,date1)-combination exists in both tables? Or can there be an entry (X, 40) in B and not in A and you still want to have (X,30) because only (X,30) is in both tables?

Comment: Yes.combination exists for every (user_name,date1). And I need  only the matching reocrds in both tables wrt user_name & date1.

Comment: I tried using the joins with group by but it does not satisfied my requirement i.e. " select * from A join (select user_name,max(date1) from A join B on A.user_name=B.user_name and A.date1=B.date1 group by user_name) Q                    on A.user_name=Q.user_name and A.date1=B.date1"                                                                                    but these query will retrieve only the user_name,max date1 for table B but I need the complete record wrt max date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since according to your comment every combination (user_name, date1) exists in both tables, you can use e.g.

```
select a.*, b.count3, b.count4, b.status 
from tableA as a
join tableB as b
on a.user_name = b.user_name and   
   a.date1 = b.date1 
where not exists 
   (select 1 from tableA as a1
    where a1.user_name = a.user_name
      and a1.date1 > a.date1);
```

You want to have an index on `(user_name, date1)` to speed it up.

As a side note: If every entry in `tableA` has exactly 1 entry in `tableB` and vice-versa (it's not clear from your description if that is the case, but it looks like it), and thus `(user_name, date1)` would be a primary key in both tables, you absolutely should add the columns `count3`, `count4` and `status` to `tableA` and get rid of `tableB`. You can still use the above code (without `join`) to find only the max entry per user.

Comment: Yes.Your query looks like absolutely right.When I am in the ofc I will check and let u know the status.                                                          And I achieved the same thing with following approach "First I used inner join to compare the two tables then I performed "ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION" i.e. " select user_name,status,count3,count4 from (select user_name,status,count3,count4,row_number() over(partition by user_name order by date1 desc) as rn from t2)   as T where rn=1;"                       Thanks for ur help Solarflare.Thanks for ur support.

Comment: @rajesh mallela In Mysql? Neat :-) Btw, even on mssql you should try this, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION` might be overkill for this problem. And since `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION` works for you, you can have the same primary key on both tables, so think about building just one table as mentioned in my side note.

Comment: Hey buddy,I am getting following error while using your query i.e. "For Exists/Not Exists operator SubQuery must be Correlated.". Any solution for these kind of errors.

Comment: My code is for mysql. For mssql you have to give the table aliases to use them in a subquery. Give me a minute, I will change that (it should then work for both mysql and mssql).

Comment: I tested it with Hive. You are right it might definitely works for MySQL. But Hive is bit different from MySQL.

Comment: Well, you tagged your question with mysql, so I answered it for mysql. But that new code should now work on hive too.